# I stopped sendmail service and started postfix. Sendmail still shows in email logs?

Tags: linux, email, postfix, sendmail

This server has both sendmail and postfix installed. Sendmail has been running but is not working properly. I stopped the sendmail service and started postfix.
Confirmed only postfix is running by checking the output of what is listening on port 25.

```
lsof -i :25
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME

master  119640 root   12u  IPv4 28103863      0t0  TCP localhost:smtp (LISTEN)

master  119640 root   13u  IPv6 28103864      0t0  TCP localhost:smtp (LISTEN)
```

Then I test sending mail:

```
echo "My message" | mail -s testing root@server.domain.com
```

It doesn't arrive in root's inbox. So I take a look at the logs at /var/log/maillog and see sendmail is still being used:

```
Feb 26 16:18:13 server sendmail[1582]: w1QLIC8N001582: to=root@server.domain, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=30233, relay=exchangeserver.domain. [x.x.x.x], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (<201802262118.w1QLIC8N001582@root@server.domain> Queued mail for delivery)
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The `mail` program runs `sendmail` to deliver the mail (in the client mode, no listening port is being open in the process). Read the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mail) for detailed information. You may change the MDA by setting the `sendmail` variable:

> **sendmail**
>
> To use an alternate mail delivery system, set this option to the full pathname of the program to use.  This should be used with care.

```
$ sendmail=/usr/bin/someothersendmail mail somebody@somewhere.com
Subject: asdf
... and so on
```

But as mail expects the MDA to recognize sendmail's options, I don't really se the use for it.

Another possibility is to use an [external SMTP server](https://www.binarytides.com/linux-mailx-command/) instead of `sendmail`.

```
$ echo "This is the message body and contains the message" | mailx -v \
> -r "someone@example.com" \
> -s "This is the subject" \
> -S smtp="mail.example.com:587" \
> -S smtp-use-starttls \
> -S smtp-auth=login \
> -S smtp-auth-user="someone@example.com" \
> -S smtp-auth-password="abc123" \
> -S ssl-verify=ignore \
> yourfriend@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This log line is not from anything listening on TCP port 25. It looks like root's `crontab` is submitting mail directly via sendmail. Or it's  some non-standard root-owned background process.

Comment: That log line is generated after I try manually sending an email using the line right above it.
'mail -s' should not be using sendmail after i stopped it, right?

Comment: @ZebDp It's independent. And that mail doesn't flow through your port 25 at all.